# How to get image thumbnail from Youtub video in swift

Tags: swift, video, youtube

I'm trying to get a thumbnail from a youtube video.
By the way, Youtube has different Urls when I register.
Is there any good method?

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service**. Please read through the Help Center, in particular: [ask]. If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck, post your code and a clear description of the problem. Also, remember to include an [mcve]. People will be glad to help if you improve your question.

Comment: Please [use the EDIT option to improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64807100/edit). Show code of how you load a picture from website in Swift then we can improve it to use Youtube images.  Your question is not clear... Where are you registering? What has a register got to do with thumbnail? Can you load image in Swift (have you practised from reading the manual)?

Answer (score 1):

You get the thumbnail of the Youtube video by this link: 
(where `XXXX` is the video ID coming after `watch?v=`):

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XXXX/hqdefault.jpg
```

For example: (Disney's *"Raya and The Last Dragon"* trailer)

```
video ID is... 9BPMTr-NS9s
video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BPMTr-NS9s
thumb: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9BPMTr-NS9s/hqdefault.jpg
```